# Reading Windows Display settings

Tags: c#, windows-7

Under Control Panel > Display a user can select Smaller/Medium/Larger for changing the size of various display elements in Windows. In my windows form app how can I detect the currently selected value?

I've tried searching but most of the answers are along the line of measuring DPI:

```
float dpiX, dpiY;
Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
dpiX = graphics.DpiX;
dpiY = graphics.DpiY;
```

Which returns 96/120/96 respectively for the 3 settings, and in any case is there really no way just tell which of these 3 radio settings a user has selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a registry to detect this.

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop

**LogPixels** attribute change every time, when i'm switching options in Display.

100% - **96**

125% - **120**

150% - **144**

But i'm not sure if values will be same on every monitor and resolution. You need to check it.

Comment: Hmm, I got 96/120/144 respectively.

Comment: Ops, same here :)